# Add-Content interspersed with redirection to file, strange formatting

Tags: powershell, logging, io

I have a simple script like this

```
$logfile = "C:\test.log"
Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "Add-Content Message"
$result= CallMyFunction -Verbose 4>> $logFile

function CallMyFunction()
{
  [OutputType([string[]])]
  [CmdletBinding()]
   param(
  )
  Write-Verbose "Verbose Message 1"
  Write-Verbose "Verbose Message 2"
  Write-Output "Return Value"
}
```

When you check test.log you will get the following:

**Add-Content Message

V e r b o s e M e s s a g e 1 V e r b o s e M e s s a g e 2**

Why is the second line of the log formatted in the way it is, with a space between each character? Interestingly if I stick with either redirects or Add-Content to append results to the log file it is formatted appropriately. What is the difference I am missing about when both are used together?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems to happen with the >> redirection operator no matter what you pass to it. I tested with

```
'test' >> $logfile
```

And got the same behavior. I think it is because it is redirecting the output stream rather than feeding a string to the file.

I tried it the following way, which sends verbose output to the default standard output stream first and then use Add-Content to write to the file and it formats it in a more expected way.

```
$result= CallMyFunction -Verbose 4>&1 | Add-Content -Path $logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a difference in encodings used to write to the output file. `Add-Content` uses ASCII as the default encoding, but the redirection operators use Unicode (since that is the default for `Out-File`).

To solve this, specify the encoding for `Add-Content`:

```
Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "Add-Content Message" -Encoding Unicode
```